# GAE: how to get current server IP?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm hosting my app on Google App Engine. Is there any posibility to get server IP of my app for ***current*** request?

*More info:*
GAE has a specific IP addressing. All http requests go to my 3-level domain, and IP of this domain isn't fixed, it changes rather frequently and can be different on different computers at the same moment. Can I somehow find out, what IP address client is requesting now?

Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to get IP of the **current GAE instance**, not the client IP? For what? You will not be able to communicate with your app using this IP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're looking for, but you can retrieve that type of information from the WSGI environmental variables.  The method of retrieving them varies with WSGI servers, and the number of variables made available to your application depends on the web server configuration.

That being said, getting client IP address is a common task and there is likely a method on the request object of the web framework you are using.

What framework are you using?